# How to block ads in youtube Android player?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using Youtube Android player in my application to play youtube videos.

player.loadVideo(videoid,start);

Before my video started ,I am getting ads.How can I block these ads in my Youtube Android player.

can I do anything programatically to block ads?

Please suggest

Comment: You can't block ads. But, at the moment, the web based player has no ads in it. This may change in the future.
You can find an implementation here: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player

Comment: Using (https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player) I had a single advertisement, the "onApiChange()" call popped to notify of the ad.
I fail to get another advertisement, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Note that per the [YouTube API terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms), this behavior is strictly prohibited. Under "prohibitions":

> modify, replace, interfere with or block advertisements placed by YouTube in the YouTube Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or the YouTube player;

You are not allowed to do this.